# Java 継承について

Tags: java

*Product*という親クラスと、*Product*を継承する*FoldingBike*という子クラスが存在しているのですが、*FoldingBike*で施されたgetGear()というコンストラクタを親クラスである*Product*で使いたいと考えております。*this.getGear()*で出来ると考えていたのですがエラーとなってしまいます。

```
public class Product {

    String brand;
    int weight;
    Boolean light; 
    String color;
    int price;

    public Product(String brand, int weight, Boolean light, String color, int price) {
        this.brand  = brand;
        this.weight =weight;
        this.light = light;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String result = this.getGear();
        }
    }


public class FoldingBike extends Product {

    int size;
    int gear;

    public FoldingBike(String brand, int weight, Boolean light, String color, int price, int size, int gear) {

        super(brand, weight, light, color, price);
        this.size = size;
        this.gear = gear;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int getGear() {
        return gear;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Product` に、抽象メソッドとして `getGear()` を宣言する

```
public abstract int getGear();
```

ことで `Product` のメソッドでも `getGear()` が存在するとみなせるようになります。

`new FoldingBike(...)` で作成したオブジェクトであれば `getGear()` は `FoldingBike` の `getGear()` が用いられ、想定通りの挙動になるかと思います。

ただしこのとき `Product` 自身は `getGear()` の実装を持っていないのでインスタンス化できません(つまり、`new Product(...)`はコンパイルエラーになります)。

```
// "abstract" を付与する必要あり
public abstract class Product {

    // 省略

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        final int gear = this.getGear();
        // ...
    }

    // Prductを継承した具象クラス(今回の場合FoldingBike)で実装しています、という宣言
    public abstract int getGear();

    public abstract int getSize();
}
```

---

抽象メソッド/抽象クラス についての公式の説明はこちらになります(英語):

- [Abstract Methods and Classes (The Java™ Tutorials >        

          Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

(補足: 比較的基本的な概念なので、検索すれば日本語の解説も多くあるかと思います)

基底クラスである `Product` では `FoldingBike` やその他派生クラス全てが持つ共通のふるまい/性質を表現しますが、それらのうちの一部の実装は派生クラスごとに異なる、という場合に利用します。

`Product` は必ず `gear` も `size` も持っている(数えることができる)が、その持ち方(数え方)は、プロダクトの種類(折り畳み自転車なのか、別のプロダクトなのか)によって異なる、ような場合に利用できる手段です。

Comment: 想定通りに動きましたありがとうございます。　なぜpublic abstract int getGear()とするとFoldingBikeクラスのgetGear()と同じ働きをするのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

### `getGear()`というコンストラクタ

「コンストラクタ」ではなく、メソッドですが、通常のオブジェクト指向言語で「継承」と言うのは、「親から子へ」とメソッドなどが引き継がれることを指します。「子から親へ」継承されることはありません。(実験レベルのマイナーな言語ではあるかもしれませんが。)

あなたのコードで言うと、`Product`のインスタンスには`gear`なんてフィールドは無い訳ですが、それに対して`getGear()`を呼び出すと、一体どんな値が返ってくるのでしょうか?

例えば「無かったら0とかで良い」と言うのであれば、親クラスである`Product`側に`getGear()`を定義しておかないといけません。

```
public class Product {

    String brand;
    int weight;
    boolean light; 
    String color;
    int price;

    public Product(String brand, int weight, boolean light, String color, int price) {
        this.brand  = brand;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.light = light;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = String.valueOf(this.getGear());
        return result;
    }

    public int getGear() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

こうすると子クラス側の`getGear()`は継承したメソッドをオーバライドしていることになります。

(今回の問題とは直接関係ないですが、lightの定義に`Boolean`を使う必要はないと思われたので、`boolean`に書き換えてあります。(大文字の)`Boolean`が必要になることは滅多にありませんが、もしそちらが必要なのであれば理由を教えてください。)

子クラスのメソッドを親クラスで使おうとするあたり、まだ継承に関する理解が不十分なように思われます。この回答で分かりにくい点があれば、コメントするなり、質問文を編集して情報を付け足すなりしてお知らせください。

Comment: 質問や回答とはあまり関係のないコメントです。私もこれまで安直に`Boolean`を使っていましたが、`boolean`との違いを知るよい機会になりました。今回は`Boolean`を使う意味は思いつきませんが、`Boolean`の使いどころが少し分かった気がします。